# Why is website at domain.com not working while www.domain.com does?

Tags: jquery, ajax, dns, lightbox

Here is the working page: game on glove dot com

The non-working page is the same URL minus the "www.".

Now try clicking on the items in the gallery at the top left of the page to the left of the youtube video. They pop a lightbox window in one version but not the other.

Also try clicking the "click here to order" button. A popup appears in both versions of the webpage, but once you make your selection and then click the button on that lightboxed window, you will see an error on the domain.com version, but not on the www.domain.com version.

Am I missing something ridiculous?

Comment: The lightbox is flash. Do you have acccess to the actionscript it uses ? Can you also post the relevant js/jQuery too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because the domain.com backend script that processes the requests sends a 302 Moved Temporarily if it's requested without the www.

I'm not sure if the jQuery ajax implementation tries to follow the 302 or not, but even if it did, it wouldn't be able to fetch the content because it's on a different domain and so is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

The easiest solution would be to update the backend processing script to remove the 302 redirect. Alternatively, forcefully redirect all traffic from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com

Comment: As a quick fix I directed all traffic from gameonglove.com to www.gameonglove.com. I'm still not sure why the domain tacked onto the beginning of "/apps/site/backend/additemtocart.nl" in the ajax requests is www.gameonglove.com instead of gameonglove.com (the requesting URL's domain).

Comment: @Lauren: It's because the actual webserver is doing the redirect from gameonglove.com to www.gameonglove.com when the URL is requested.

Comment: Now that the redirect is in effect that's true, but I'm confused about before, when the gameonglove.com domain didn't redirect to www.gameonglove.com, and yet the ajax request was still using www.gameonglove.com as the domain.

Answer (score 3):

Since the object is flash it needs a policy file to have permissions to execute javascript code. And it might be being loaded from www.don't want this page being indexed so well under the website domain.com as opposed from domain.com which would break its the crossdomain policy as they are not considered the same domain. So you have to change the cross domain policy file to include all subdomains

Example should be (if im not mistaken):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*.domain.com" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: This is all being done in Javascript using jQuery.ajax to pull the page, and the page is being requested without a domain, so I don't think it's a cross-domain issue.

Comment: It cant be all done in javascript the box that contains the objects to click on live in a flash object, the lightbox itself is javascript.

Comment: looks like they changed it to force the www anyway too so lol

Comment: @Alex it most definitely is, how can a page be requested without domain?

Comment: I meant to say it's not the Flash cross-domain issues that require a flash policy file to fix. Some of the UI elements are Flash, yes, but the actual ordering process and the error occur completely in Javascript. @Agos: I meant that the ajax request does not specify the domain. The POST into the backend to proceed through checkout uses jQuery.ajax with a URL of `/apps/site/backend/additemtocart.nl`, so it's not like the client script is using the wrong domain.

Comment: And i see what Alex was meaning, for the Click To Order button yes that was all jquery actions. I was talking about the box above it.

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the "Click To Order" button you return a 302 redirect status with a location to the www which your ajax call cannot follow due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Screenshot below

[image]